# The text inside some divs get out of place when they are displayed in EI7

Tags: html, css

The text inside those divs http://ada.kiexpro.com/html/photo.html get out of place when they are displayed in IE7?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your css for class "inword", "photobox", "photo". Also check you properly close div or not.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like IE7 is defaulting to a large top-margin on P tags, try this CSS:

```
p{margin-top:0}
```